# Meteor mdg:validated-method without using simple schema

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, simple-schema

Well,

[Simple Schema is in the middle of transitioning to a new version 2.0](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/640#issuecomment-241933838)

And at the same time, I'm not really sure I'd like to use this in my project.

I am writing an ES6 React based Meteor application therefor I'd like to make use of [The "Advanced" way to create meteor methods](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#validated-method).  However, I don't want to use aldeed:simple-schema at all.

Is there a way to put in a custom validation method here?

This doesn't work:

```
export const addSuggestion = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'suggestion.add',
  validate() {
    return true
  },
  run(incommingSuggestion) {
    // do things which are not relevant to this question.
  }
})
```

It produces the following error:

```
Error: Returning from validate doesn't do anything; perhaps you meant to throw an error?(…)
```

Is there a different way to write this?

> Perhaps I need to not use this ***validated-method***, instead I should maybe write it out [long-form](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#advanced-boilerplate)? ***Edit:*** <s>**Edit:** This works, you can write everything out long-form with all of this extra boiler plate if you want to avoid validation all together for the time being.  For now this is the solution I will use until I finally decide on how I will be validating everything.  I'm not sure what to do right now because Simple Schema is in transition.</s> - Actually that doesn't work, it for some reason never returns a value and I couldn't get around that.

Anyone out there know how to get around this?

Obviously googling has not turned up any results, I've been looking at this problem now for more than three days.

Comment: Simple-schema is almost _de rigueur_ in MeteorJS projects. I'm not sure validated-methods can function without them.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Yeah, you're right - it really is.  But recently it's been involved with a change from a "1.0" version to a "2.0" version and 2.0 is not currently stable enough for production.  I'm going to stick to regular old check/match for now.  Thanks for your comment though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-implement SimpleSchema's API, but why?

SimpleSchema is a de facto standard in Meteor, like Mongoose for Node<->MongoDB.  There are alternatives in the works, but I think you're pushing the bleeding edge.

If you've got work to do, use SimpleSchema.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - You're right, simple-schema is the de facto way to do this.  I was just looking around for another way - check/match will do what I need here perfectly.  Do you have any advice against that?

Comment: @JeremyIglehart use what works :-)  I found after a certain complexity SS was better.  The nice thing is you don't have to copy paste every time you check.  But it always depends.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Perhaps you know of a good guide for SS - the ReadMe is a bit scattered and difficult to understand.  Do I want to use collection2 also?  Simple-Schema failing build right now, and 2.0 is on the brink of possibly becoming stable?  Then Collection2 and Autoform lag behind that... I'm just a bit confused as to what to choose for this right now, as everything seams to be in "flux" (no pun intended).  All I want is validation, really.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, those are good questions.  I don't depend on ss directly.  If you `meteor add collection2 autoform` it should handle the dependencies for simpleschema.  I'm using ss 1.5.3, collection2 2.9.1 and autoform 5.8.1

Answer (score 0):

From the [Meteor Forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-meteor-mdg-validated-method-without-using-simple-schema/28722/2?u=autoschematic):

Firstly, the `Meteor method` should expect an object like so:

```
myMethod.call({
  arg1: 'hello',
  arg2: 25,
}, (error, result) => { /* do stuff */ });
```

And then your method would be defined as such: ***(Note, that*** `validate() { }` ***is empty, before I was returning*** `true` ***- this was the problem I was having)***

```
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const myMethod = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'myMethod',
  validate() { }, // always valid
  run({ arg1, arg2 }) {
    // do things
  }
};
```

When you're ready to validate the arguments, just change validate accordingly:

```
validate(opts) {
  check(opts, {
    arg1: String,
    arg2: Number,
  }
},
```

And this way we can avoid using Simple-Schema while it works out it's transition from 1.0 to 2.0 (Good luck Simple Schema!!!)

And thanks to [ffxsam](https://forums.meteor.com/users/ffxsam) for providing [the solution](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-meteor-mdg-validated-method-without-using-simple-schema/28722/2?u=autoschematic) on the meteor forums!